# Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion in Wso2IS

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have enable SSO in wso2 esb page ,it used to work fine previously but since we have changed the certificated in IS and ESB. now while trying to login to ESB via IS i get : Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid.
I have added both Esb and IS cert to both wso2is and wso2esb keystore as well.
Still the error persists .

```
2015-05-28 09:59:17,281 log_level=WARN  thread=http-nio-9443-exec-24 logger=org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature [Signature verification failed.]
2015-05-28 09:59:17,281 log_level=WARN  thread=http-nio-9443-exec-24 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil [Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid.]
2015-05-28 09:59:17,281 log_level=DEBUG thread=http-nio-9443-exec-24 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil [org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Signature Validation Failed for the SAML Assertion : Signature is invalid.]
2015-05-28 09:59:17,281 log_level=WARN  thread=http-nio-9443-exec-24 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor [Signature validation for Authentication Request failed.]
2015-05-28 09:59:33,747 log_level=DEBUG thread=pool-29-thread-1 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService [Start running the Session Data cleanup task.]
2015-05-28 09:59:33,759 log_level=DEBUG thread=pool-29-thread-1 logger=org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService [Stop running the Session Data cleanup task.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the keystore of both WSO2IS and WSO2ESB,  then you need to export the certificate of the primary keystore of the WSO2IS and import it to WSO2ESB's primary keystore.  Then you need specify the `alias` name that you used to import the certificate in to WSO2ESB's primary keystore. This must be configured in the `/repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml` file under following property.

`<Parameter name="IdPCertAlias">wso2carbon</Parameter>`